# Weight python mistake SyntaxError

Tags: python, input, syntax-error, user-input

I'm reviewing Python again and I came to this early stage where I'm stuck again.
I need to:

> Write a program in Python that will ask for the user's
>       Name and 'weight' in kilograms. The program will then
>       Output a sentence informing the user of their weight in grams and in pounds.

This is my code:

```
myName = str(input('What is your name?:'))

myWeight = int(input( myName+ 'What is your weight in kilograms?:')

weightGrams = 'myWeight*1000'
weightPounds = 'myWeight*2.2'



print(myName+ 'You would weigh', weightGrams, 'in grams and' weightPounds, 'in pounds!')
```

I am not getting the correct output and also I am getting SyntaxErrors.
The SyntaxErrors are here:

```
weightGrams = 'myWeight*1000'
weightPounds = 'myWeight*2.2'
```

And at the end:

```
print(myName+ 'You would weigh', weightGrams, 'in grams and' weightPounds, 'in pounds!')
```

How can I fix those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't treat `int` as `string`:

```
weightGrams = myWeight*1000
weightPounds = myWeight*2.2
```

Also you have syntax errors in your `print`:

```
print(myName+ ' You would weigh', weightGrams, 'in grams and', weightPounds, 'in pounds!')
```

In addition you don't need the cast to `str` here since `input` already gives out a `string`:

```
myName = input('What is your name?:')
```

**Final edit**: you are missing a closing bracket `)` here:

```
myWeight = int(input( myName+ 'What is your weight in kilograms?:'))
```

Comment: ii tried it but comes out as invalid syntax

Comment: wait oh let me try again didn't see the top part

Comment: I edited with a fix to your syntax errors too

Comment: I keep getting syntax error..?

Comment: Where? That isn't likely, I am running the same code

Comment: let me edit the question and show you how I wrote it

Comment: Look at my **final edit** it should be that :)

Comment: oh I got it LOL thx a lot dude appreciate it